# How to select multiple svg texts in a single customized zoom function

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

I am working on the zoom function of d3 but I am not able to zoom on two different text(labels).
text code: (they are working)

```
   var texts = canvas.selectAll("text")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter();


   texts.append("text")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
        .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.name;; });


   texts.append("text")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x ; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 20; })  // for not overlapping name and the title
        .attr("dy", ".45em")
        .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
        .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.title; });
```

Zoom Code: (second part not working)

```
      function zoom(d, i) {
         var k = r / d.r / 2;
         x.domain([d.x - d.r, d.x + d.r]);
         y.domain([d.y - d.r, d.y + d.r]);

       var t = canvas.transition()
                      .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750);

     t.selectAll("text")
             .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
             .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
             .style("opacity", 0.15 });


     t.selectAll("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 20 })
              .style("opacity", 0.15 });
      }
```

Now the question is how to keep the displacement  (d.y + 20; })  done in text2 part as both of them overlapping during zoom operation... I also used variable instead of using the text but none of them worked.. Any help

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, here is the code but it is not working (this is the first time I am using jfiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/santy14/w5n30dya/8/